# org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value With db mysql

Tags: hibernate

This is a prime example of the application hibernate, I have this error I tried to solve the problem by adding the auto increment to the table on the mysql db but does not change the error

```
        <hibernate-mapping>
           <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
              <meta attribute="class-description">
                 This class contains the employee detail. 
              </meta>
              <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
                 <generator class="native"/>
              </id>
              <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
              <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
              <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
           </class>
        </hibernate-mapping>
```

This is a prime example of the application hibernate, I have this error I tried to solve the problem by adding the auto increment to the table on the mysql db but does not change the error

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">
          org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
       </property>

       <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
          jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/anagrafica
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
          root
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
          root
       </property>

       <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
       <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>



public class Employee {
   private int id;
   private String firstName; 
   private String lastName;   
   private int salary;  

   public Employee() {}
   public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
      this.firstName = fname;
      this.lastName = lname;
      this.salary = salary;
   }
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId( int id ) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
      this.firstName = first_name;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
      this.lastName = last_name;
   }
   public int getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }
   public void setSalary( int salary ) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}



import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator; 

import org.hibernate.HibernateException; 
import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ManageEmployee {
   private static SessionFactory factory; 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
         factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      }catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }
      ManageEmployee ME = new ManageEmployee();

      /* Add few employee records in database */
      Integer empID1 = ME.addEmployee("Zara", "Ali", 1000);
      Integer empID2 = ME.addEmployee("Daisy", "Das", 5000);
      Integer empID3 = ME.addEmployee("John", "Paul", 10000);

      /* List down all the employees */
      ME.listEmployees();

      /* Update employee's records */
      ME.updateEmployee(empID1, 5000);

      /* Delete an employee from the database */
      ME.deleteEmployee(empID2);

      /* List down new list of the employees */
      ME.listEmployees();
   }
   /* Method to CREATE an employee in the database */
   public Integer addEmployee(String fname, String lname, int salary){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      Integer employeeID = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
         employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
      return employeeID;
   }
   /* Method to  READ all the employees */
   public void listEmployees( ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         List employees = session.createQuery("FROM Employee").list(); 
         for (Iterator iterator = 
                           employees.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            Employee employee = (Employee) iterator.next(); 
            System.out.print("First Name: " + employee.getFirstName()); 
            System.out.print("  Last Name: " + employee.getLastName()); 
            System.out.println("  Salary: " + employee.getSalary()); 
         }
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
   /* Method to UPDATE salary for an employee */
   public void updateEmployee(Integer EmployeeID, int salary ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = 
                    (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID); 
         employee.setSalary( salary );
         session.update(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
   /* Method to DELETE an employee from the records */
   public void deleteEmployee(Integer EmployeeID){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = 
                   (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID); 
         session.delete(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to use the `auto_increment` in Your database table.  The Table  table definition some thing like the below format,

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
SALARY INT, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I had already added auto increment but was not on the database because imostato to set a field auto increment this must also be the primary key field, and that I had not declared as primary key.
Now it works. thanks

Comment: No need to say thanks in Stackoverflow. We use upvote/downvote for appreciating the answers of Stackoverflow.

Comment: ok I imagined it a habit, however currently I do not have enough reputation to vote.

Answer (score 0):

No other solution can work better unless you use the following annotation

please use

```
 @GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
```

reply me back . if its not working